# How to copy table from MS SQL Server 2012 to MonetDB

Tags: sql-server, monetdb

Table dump file is about 30Gib. So, when I load its contents into MonetDB, I get several exceptions ( "Null byte in input", "unexpected ON, expecting '=' in: set ansi_nulls on", unexpected '[' in: "create table [" and etc.), because this file is formated in mssql-way. How to copy from mssql to monetDb?

UPD: To copy from csv, I use these scripts in SQuirreL

```
CREATE TABLE "PageTracking"(
    "PageTrackingID" bigint,
    "TimeStamp" date,
    "Hash" varchar(50) ,
    "UserIP" varchar(16) ,
    "UserAgent" varchar(1000) ,
    "UserID" varchar(16) ,
    "SessionID" varchar(16) ,
    "Page" varchar(20) ,
    "DocId" int ,
    "Url" varchar(500) ,
    "Referer" varchar(500) ,
    "Rank" int ,
    "Total" int 
)
```

And then

```
COPY OFFSET 2 INTO "PageTracking" FROM 'f:\tmp\pagetracking.csv'
```

When I use MonetDb Client, I receive:

```
sql>copy offset 2 into sys.pagetraking from 'f:\tmp\pagetracking.csv';
COPY INTO: no such table 'pagetraking'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going via the CSV route. The `CREATE TABLE` syntax is different between the systems. Also, error messages like `Null byte in input` suggest some data cleansing is required as well.